# Project 2010 Leveling / Level by Task ID

Tags: project-management, microsoft-project

Likely not a great place to ask this question, but I'm not getting traction on MS Project 2010 forums.

I dont' use Project often (cause I'm a developer) but when I do, I change a the "level algorithum" in Project to using Task ID as priority.

This is not a well known feature, but rather than add dependencies, and resources into a simple plan before leveling it - this change in the leveling algorithum causes all tasks to level just like they were connected via the Finish-Start dependency, in the order of their Task ID.

It's beautiful, and makes Project work nicely when laying down a very linear plan like a software development project.

In previous versions, this change was made under Project, Options, Advanced .... I haven't used it for years, but it was there in 2007.

Wondering if it's still there in 2010... I found the File, Options, Advanced - but can't see where the leveling calculation is.  It seems they have gone to either a fully manual mode, or a fully automatic mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the ribbon, select the resource tab, then select "Leveling Options" - there is a drop down box about halfway down the dialog for "Leveling order", which may be what you are after.